# can i make linear regression predict like a classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I trained a linear regression model(using sklearn with python3),
my train set was with 94 features and the class of them was 0 or 1..
than i went to check my linear regression model on the test set and it gave me those results:

1.`[ 0.04988957]` its real value is 0 on the test set

2.`[ 0.00740425]` its real value is 0 on the test set

3.`[ 0.01907946]` its real value is 0 on the test set

4.`[ 0.07518938]` its real value is 0 on the test set

5.`[ 0.15202335]` its real value is 0 on the test set

6.`[ 0.04531345]` its real value is 0 on the test set

7.`[ 0.13394644]` its real value is 0 on the test set

8.`[ 0.16460608]` its real value is 1 on the test set

9.`[ 0.14846777]` its real value is 0 on the test set

10.`[ 0.04979875]` its real value is 0 on the test set

as you can see that at row 8 it gave the highest value but the thing is that i want to use my_model.predict(testData) and it will give only 0 or 1 as results, how can i possibly do it? the model got any threshold or auto cutoff that i can use?

Comment: Which sklearn model are you using?

Comment: from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression (see [sci-kit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) or [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/discretemod.html) implementation) is the right tool here; it outperforms OLS in most cases and its predictions naturally lie in the interval (0, 1).

Answer (score 1):

There is a linear classifier `sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifer(alpha=0.)` that you can use for this. Setting the Ridge penalty to 0. makes it do exactly the linear regression you want and set the threshold to divide between classes.

Answer (score 0):

The `LinearRegression` class does not have a classifier on it.  However there is an [SGD Classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) (also a linear model) that can create the predictions you wants

Example code from documentation

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn import linear_model
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
>>> Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
>>> clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
>>> clf.fit(X, Y)
... 
SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, average=False, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1,
        eta0=0.0, fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15,
        learning_rate='optimal', loss='hinge', n_iter=5, n_jobs=1,
        penalty='l2', power_t=0.5, random_state=None, shuffle=True,
        verbose=0, warm_start=False)
>>> print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
```